# Network Inspector keep crashing in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

Its been more than 3 days. I tried a lot of things but the Network Inspector keep crashing after updated to Bumblebee

[image]

Comment: I got the same problem, have you found a solution for this?

Comment: No, Still facing same issue

Comment: I opened an Issue on Google´s Issue Tracker, it is not solved yet, but thay have some leads, apparently it's related to a dependency, are you using androidx.work:work-runtime:2.5.0 or higher in your project? I do. I tried the Network Inspector on other project and it works fine. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the info, for me too able to see that it's working fine on another project. So I think we have to wait for new update

Comment: I'm seeing this as well.  Here's the issue tracker: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/219563755?pli=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also solved, by updating to latest Stable Android version - which is Chipmunk (version 2021.2.1) as of 05/12/2022.

https://developer.android.com/studio/

Answer (score 2):

i had the same problem.

https://developer.android.com/studio/archive

I solved the problem by downloading **Android Studio Dolphin (2021.3.1) Canary 7**.

If the error persists, you can track it here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/219563755